# alert the marker value in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to alert the value in the marker so that I can submit a form and pass the value to my servlet to do some processing. I am new to google maps, i am so confused to get this working. `infoWindow` works fine, when I hover over, it shows the location name and little description and when i mouseout the infowindow closes. I am not able to alert the clicked marker value. Can anyone guide me.

```
for (i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[i][2], location[i][3]),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
                var content = contentString + location[i][0] + " - " +  location[i][1] + "</DIV>";
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(content);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                infowindow.close();
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            alert(location[i][0].trim());

            });

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve in similar way as for `mouseover` event listener:

```
    (function(i) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            alert(location[i][0].trim());
        });
    })(i);
```

Otherwise error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

is reported because `i` is set past last entry of `location` array.